# vue not found in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, vue-cli, docker-container

I am trying to run vue/cli in a docker container.
I started the container went to cli of the container through `docker exec -it` command and entered the command `npm install @vue/cli`. Now, when I see the package.json file of the container, I see the package installed but when I try to create a project with the command `vue create <project-name>` it shows `vue command not found`.

```
{
  "name": "node_dock_2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node with docker with vue.js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "website",
    "Docker",
    "vue.js",
    "vue/cli"
  ],
  "author": "Viraj",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "^4.5.15",
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

This is the message when I try to install @vue/cli: (`npm install @vue/cli`)

```
up to date, audited 943 packages in 12s

68 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

14 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 8 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

This is my Dockerfile (Dockerfile, index.js and package.json are in same directory).

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "/index.js"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A Docker image usually contains a complete application and its runtime dependencies; why try to create a new application inside a running container?  I'd also normally expect commands like `npm` to write out text-format errors, not PNG files; can you edit the question to include the text of the errors you're getting and not screen shots?

Comment: npm install -g @vue/cli && export PATH=$PATH:/root/.npm-global/bin

Comment: @DavidMaze I had added the vue/cli package in the image

Comment: @RakeshGupta should I type those 2 commands inside the container?

Comment: Yes, inside the container and to the Dockerfile eventually

Comment: Thanks @RakeshGupta it worked, but what does the `export PATH=$PATH:/root/.npm-global/bin` command do ?? If you can write an answer with explanation I can accept that answer

Comment: Glad that you could make it work. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it seems like that your container does not have correct PATH to look for vue binary

##### [PATH variable](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bb/cs348/www-S08/unix_path.html)

> It's essentially a : separated list of directories. When you execute a
> command, the shell searches through each of these directories, one by
> one, until it finds a directory where the executable exists

##### Install vue/clie globally first with -g option

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

##### Append to your container's existing PATH variable to include the /root/.npn-global/bin folder. This will allow the system find the vue binary

```
export PATH=$PATH:/root/.npm-global/bin
```

You should update your Dockerfile accordingly to make these changes permanent.

Comment: wait, what update should be done in Dockerfile?

Comment: If your container restarts, you will lose the changes that you made inside the container. Hence, the correct way is to set it in the Dockerfile using ENV. Please refer to this
https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-vue-app/